# tar command in for loop starts from the wrong number

Tags: scripting, for, variable-substitution

backup/ has the following files.

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-8-46:~/$ ls backup/
itrpl_dsm_10_1.tif  itrpl_dsm_12_3.tif  itrpl_dsm_2_3.tif  itrpl_dsm_4_3.tif  itrpl_dsm_6_3.tif  itrpl_dsm_8_3.tif
itrpl_dsm_10_2.tif  itrpl_dsm_12_4.tif  itrpl_dsm_2_4.tif  itrpl_dsm_4_4.tif  itrpl_dsm_6_4.tif  itrpl_dsm_8_4.tif
itrpl_dsm_10_3.tif  itrpl_dsm_12_5.tif  itrpl_dsm_2_5.tif  itrpl_dsm_4_5.tif  itrpl_dsm_6_5.tif  itrpl_dsm_8_5.tif
itrpl_dsm_10_4.tif  itrpl_dsm_12_6.tif  itrpl_dsm_2_6.tif  itrpl_dsm_4_6.tif  itrpl_dsm_6_6.tif  itrpl_dsm_8_6.tif
itrpl_dsm_10_5.tif  itrpl_dsm_12_7.tif  itrpl_dsm_2_7.tif  itrpl_dsm_4_7.tif  itrpl_dsm_6_7.tif  itrpl_dsm_8_7.tif
itrpl_dsm_10_6.tif  itrpl_dsm_12_8.tif  itrpl_dsm_2_8.tif  itrpl_dsm_4_8.tif  itrpl_dsm_6_8.tif  itrpl_dsm_8_8.tif
itrpl_dsm_10_7.tif  itrpl_dsm_1_1.tif   itrpl_dsm_3_1.tif  itrpl_dsm_5_1.tif  itrpl_dsm_7_1.tif  itrpl_dsm_9_1.tif
itrpl_dsm_10_8.tif  itrpl_dsm_1_2.tif   itrpl_dsm_3_2.tif  itrpl_dsm_5_2.tif  itrpl_dsm_7_2.tif  itrpl_dsm_9_2.tif
itrpl_dsm_11_1.tif  itrpl_dsm_1_3.tif   itrpl_dsm_3_3.tif  itrpl_dsm_5_3.tif  itrpl_dsm_7_3.tif  itrpl_dsm_9_3.tif
itrpl_dsm_11_2.tif  itrpl_dsm_1_4.tif   itrpl_dsm_3_4.tif  itrpl_dsm_5_4.tif  itrpl_dsm_7_4.tif  itrpl_dsm_9_4.tif
itrpl_dsm_11_3.tif  itrpl_dsm_1_5.tif   itrpl_dsm_3_5.tif  itrpl_dsm_5_5.tif  itrpl_dsm_7_5.tif  itrpl_dsm_9_5.tif
itrpl_dsm_11_4.tif  itrpl_dsm_1_6.tif   itrpl_dsm_3_6.tif  itrpl_dsm_5_6.tif  itrpl_dsm_7_6.tif  itrpl_dsm_9_6.tif
itrpl_dsm_11_5.tif  itrpl_dsm_1_7.tif   itrpl_dsm_3_7.tif  itrpl_dsm_5_7.tif  itrpl_dsm_7_7.tif  itrpl_dsm_9_7.tif
itrpl_dsm_11_6.tif  itrpl_dsm_1_8.tif   itrpl_dsm_3_8.tif  itrpl_dsm_5_8.tif  itrpl_dsm_7_8.tif  itrpl_dsm_9_8.tif
itrpl_dsm_11_7.tif  itrpl_dsm_2_1.tif   itrpl_dsm_4_1.tif  itrpl_dsm_6_1.tif  itrpl_dsm_8_1.tif
itrpl_dsm_11_8.tif  itrpl_dsm_2_2.tif   itrpl_dsm_4_2.tif  itrpl_dsm_6_2.tif  itrpl_dsm_8_2.tif
```

When executing

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-8-46:~/backup$ for (( i=1; i<=12; i++ )); do tar -czvf itrpl_dsm_$i.tar.gz itrpl_dsm_$i_*.tif; done
```

Output:

```
itrpl_dsm_10_1.tif
itrpl_dsm_10_2.tif
itrpl_dsm_10_3.tif
itrpl_dsm_10_4.tif
itrpl_dsm_10_5.tif
itrpl_dsm_10_6.tif
itrpl_dsm_10_7.tif
itrpl_dsm_10_8.tif
itrpl_dsm_11_1.tif
itrpl_dsm_11_2.tif
itrpl_dsm_11_3.tif
itrpl_dsm_11_4.tif
itrpl_dsm_11_5.tif
itrpl_dsm_11_6.tif
itrpl_dsm_11_7.tif
itrpl_dsm_11_8.tif
itrpl_dsm_12_3.tif
itrpl_dsm_12_4.tif
itrpl_dsm_12_5.tif
itrpl_dsm_12_6.tif
itrpl_dsm_12_7.tif
itrpl_dsm_12_8.tif
```

My intention was generating itrpl_dsm_1.tar.gz from itrpl_dsm_1_*.tif files, but apparently it didn't do what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `${i}` not `$i`. i.e.

```
for (( i=1; i<=12; i++ )); do tar -czvf itrpl_dsm_$i.tar.gz itrpl_dsm_${i}_*.tif; done
```

Because bash will look for variable name `i_`, but there is no variable with this name, so it will replaced with nothing.

So the pattern will become `itrpl_dsm_*.tif` and then `*`, wildcard will expand and it will be replaced by every file matching the pattern.